# Intel RST Raid 5 with 6 HDDs incredible slow

Tags: raid, intel, rst

maybe someone can help.

Since I upgrade our Raid5 from 4 to 6 HDDs the write-performance is VERY poor.
Read is more than 700 MB/s but write is less than 30 MB/s
Cache-Modus is Write-Back

System specifications:
Asrock H370M-ITX/ac
32 GB RAM DDR4
WD Blue SN500
6 x WD60EFRX (WD RED 6TB)
Windows Server 2019
Intel RST 17.7.0.1006

Comment: What was the write performance previously?

Comment: don't know exactly, but much more than 250 MB/s

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved -)

I donwsized the RAID to 5 HDDs: Read 610 MBytes Write 527 MBytes